# Caseta Switches 6WCL-WH-A

Tags: dimmer-switch

I think I am getting pretty close with this but not 100% there yet. I have a hallway light with two switches at each end. On / off at each end will turn the hall light on / off. Am swapping out dumb switches with Lutrons and have 2x PDW-6WCL.

(right side)

- 1x PDW-6WCL (2 black, 1 green) connecting into 1 red, 1 black, 1 white
- Green and white are separately each capped
- Lutron black connecting to switch red
- Other Lutron black connecting to switch black
- Followed this diagram here: https://webapiaw1proddat01st01.blob.core.windows.net/assets/documents/368-4493_Page_2.pdf

(left side)

- 1x PDW-6WCL (2 black, 1 green) connecting into 1 red, 2 black
- Green individually capped
- Lutron black connecting to switch red and black
- Other Lutron black connecting to remaining switch black
- Followed this diagram here (Location 1): https://webapiaw1proddat01st01.blob.core.windows.net/assets/documents/368-4493_Page_3.pdf

The dumb switches worked before, so it seems like I am not installing these correctly. Anything that I am missing?

Comment: You had 3 way switches. Each with 3 wires. On one switch a permanent hot was coming in on one screw. Then it was switched as output on two screws to the second 3 way switch. On the second switch two were coming in from the first switch and one is going out to the light.

Answer (score 2):

You're really bouncing off the walls here.  To start with, you have chosen a product that is designed to work with a master and remote.  Except you are installing 2 masters.  Further, you are using the diagram for a different application on each switch.   It's like your *expectation* is that you must install these 2 masters, and that is coloring your reading of the instructions.  It doesn'tq help that "single-pole" is unclear: "single pole" is how they describe a non-3-way setup.

Follow the first (3-way) instructions.

The switch at location 2 will be deleted altogether.  You will need a red wire nut to join 3 wires (yellow nut OK if #14 wire) and then cover it with a blank cover plate.

Then you use a Pico remote for the second switch. It's possible the Pico remote is designed to fit in a standard junction box, in which case you can install it in the above box instead of a blank cover plate. Just push all the wires to the back.

Take the 2nd master and either return it, or use it to control a different light, your call.

Note that wire nuts are not "caps".  The wires are twisted together by you twisting the wire nut Quite hard.